# textarea in phpBB style

Tags: html, css, phpbb

I am trying to implement a textarea to my custom made module in user panel in phpBB CMS.

I created a basic HTML template script, that just shows a textarea with plain text in it. Tested it on localhost, worked just like expected. As soon as I uploaded it on my website, the size of textbox has shrunk and when I right clicked -> Inspect element it said "textarea.auto-resized".

This is my code:

```
<style>
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
</style>
<textarea readonly rows="45" cols="15">Text.</textarea>
```

Is there any CSS atribute that I can set to "style" in order to prevent the browser from auto-resizing my textarea?

Comment: Please always try to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking a question to make easier help you

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```html
<style>
textarea {
  resize: none !important;
}
</style>
<textarea readonly rows="45" cols="15">Text.</textarea>
```

You can learn more about `!important` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp).

Comment: Hello, unfortunately it did not help. Browser still keeps resizing the area.

Comment: @MichaelGrabner Try setting a fixed width and height. The resize property is only for the user to resize it.

Comment: I know, I do not want that either. I already tried to set "width" and "height" in the style either for px or different measures, still, the box shrunk to certain sizes and did not go past.

Comment: @MichaelGrabner Did you use !important with width and height? What browser? Can I have your full code?

Comment: The full code is what I provided. It is just altered with header and footer of the template. I am using Firefox but I tried it on Edge with the same result.